# Android 6.0 Application crashes when I use TIdHTTP for HTTPS calls

Tags: android, delphi, indy, idhttp, boringssl

I'm using Delphi XE8 with Indy 10 for Android application development. I have used the `TIdHTTP` component for HTTP/S service calls.

It works fine in Android 5 and earlier versions, but the same is not working in Android 6.0 (when I try to access HTTPS protocols).

I tried with `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL`, but still the app is crashing when I call any service methods like PUT, POST, GET.

Please help me on this.

Comment: I'd bet that it's a NetworkOnMainThreadException. Google it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried with **TNetHTTPClient** , and it works fine with ***HTTPS*** protocols.

Answer (score 6):

Indy's *native* support for SSL/TLS is broken (well, incomplete) on Android 6+, because Google dropped support for OpenSSL in Android 6, switching to their own internal modified fork named BoringSSL:

[Android 6.0 Changes - BoringSSL](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#boringSSL)

> Android is moving away from OpenSSL to the [BoringSSL](https://boringssl.googlesource.com/boringssl/) library. If you’re using the Android NDK in your app [which Delphi Android apps do], don't link against cryptographic libraries that are not a part of the NDK API, **such as libcrypto.so and libssl.so**. These libraries are not public APIs, and may change or break without notice across releases and devices. In addition, you may expose yourself to security vulnerabilities. Instead, modify your native code to call the Java cryptography APIs via JNI **or to statically link against a cryptography library of your choice**.

`TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` does not work with BoringSSL, and Indy does not have another SSLIOHandler class for BoringSSL at this time. This is an open issue that has not been resolved yet:

[#166 Support BoringSSL on Android 6](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/166)

Until that is resolved (and there is no ETA on that), you will have to either:

1. deploy OpenSSL binaries for Android (available from https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/) with your Android app, and instruct Indy where to load them from at runtime. But depending on device and system configuration, this may or may not work. People have had mixed results on this matter.
2. write your own `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase`-derived class that uses Java socket APIs instead of C library BSD sockets and OpenSSL.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried with **TNetHTTPClient** , and it works fine with _HTTPS_ protocols. 
[http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Using_an_HTTP_Client]